# Enable x509 Authentication in Tomcat on Openshift

Tags: tomcat, ssl-certificate, web-applications, openshift-online-2

I have a web application deployed on Tomcat 7 running on Openshift. I managed to enable HTTP-to-HTTPS redirection on the server ([instruction](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/749733)).
I don't have valid certificate. So I have to use the original URL https://foo-bar.rhcloud.com (no custome URL).
Now I'd like to enable x509 authentication in my application. I know how to do it on Tomcat on my local machine. But the HTTPS connector for my application on Openshift is commented out.
I tried to add `<login-config>` to the web.xml but it didn't work (it didn't ask me for client certificate). Here's the web.xml config:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>HTTPSOnly</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>CLIENT-CERT</auth-method>
</login-config>
```

Questions:
1. How can I enable x509 authentication?
2. Since I don't have valid client certificate, how can I specify the trusted keystore for Tomcat?

Thanks in advance.